# Install one dimmer switch which is one of two regular switches

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch

We're purchasing (5) dimmable LED's for the kitchen and I'm now researching the dimmable switches.  The lights are controlled by two switches on opposite sides of the room.  Either one can turn off or turn on the lights  (So one may be up while the other down, or vice versa)
One is on a 3 gang switch. The other switch is single.

This may be somewhat of a duplicate of this question.
[Can I install a dimmer switch on a 2 way circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68269/can-i-install-a-dimmer-switch-on-a-2-way-circuit)

If it is, it sounds like it's doable, but I had questions on the actual implementation.  **What do I need to do with the regular switch?**  Do I need to leave it on, and cover it with one of these switch covers so it doesn't get switched, or do I need to replace both with dimmable (that doesn't sound like the right answer), or something else??  I'm in the USA.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that I have a 3-way switch.  Wired it according to instructions and left the 'regular' switch alone. It works great.